# How to change password of user in AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django

In creation of MyUser I was following:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

I would like to change password of user.

I try:

```
In [55]: i=FairsUser.objects.get(email="admin@andilabs.com")

In [56]: i.__dict__
Out[56]:
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x110a53490>,
 'email': u'admin@andilabs.com',
 'id': 8,
 'is_active': True,
 'is_admin': False,
 'is_superuser': False,
 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 2, 16, 0, 59, 109673),
 'mail_sent': False,
 'password': u'pbkdf2_sha256$12000$XgszxXkXbroY$PEEf3vqszclGcf7iQXeZRWDTYcCsvlGh0jH15f6rKR8='}

In [57]: i.set_password("abcd")

In [58]: i.save()
```

Then I check:

```
In [59]: i_updated=FairsUser.objects.get(email="admin@andilabs.com")

In [60]: i_updated.__dict__
Out[60]:
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x110a53590>,
 'email': u'admin@andilabs.com',
 'id': 8,
 'is_active': True,
 'is_admin': False,
 'is_superuser': False,
 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 2, 16, 0, 59, 109673),
 'mail_sent': False,
 'password': u'pbkdf2_sha256$12000$8VCDlzTuVfHF$ldwqbXo/axzMFLasqOKkddz8o1yW9d5r7gUxD3qH4sU='}
```

The values for hashed password differs, but I can not login using "abcd". What is the reason?

OK. In this case it "started" working. But In my logic in form of admin it does not still:

```
def clean(self, commit=True):
    super(UserChangeForm, self).clean()
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    old_status = FairsUser.objects.get(email=cleaned_data['email'])
    if (old_status.mail_sent is False or old_status.mail_sent is None) and cleaned_data['mail_sent'] is True:
        usr = FairsUser.objects.get(email=cleaned_data['email'])
        new_pass = ''.join(
            random.choice(
                string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
                ) for _ in range(DESIRED_PASSWORD_LENGTH))
        usr.set_password(new_pass)
        usr.save()
        mail_content = 'Hi! Bbelow are your login credentials.\n e-mail: {0} \n password: {1} \n Have nice time on fairs! \n'.format(usr.email, new_pass)
        msg = EmailMessage('Your login data', mail_content, 'from@andilabs.com', [usr.email, ])
        msg.send()
    return cleaned_data
```

The delivered by email password does not allow my to login, as well I can not authenticate in console.

Comment: You didn't show a failed `authenticate()`. Please paste a full Python session in which you can show that `set_password('abcd')` followed by `authenticate(user, 'abcd')` actually fails.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: [AbstractBaseUser change password via set\_password not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804922/abstractbaseuser-change-password-via-set-password-not-working). Please edit your existing question if you need to add more details, instead of posting a new one for the same issue.

Comment: @Ianzz Please NOTICE: The difference between trying thinds in MODEL and in FORM.

Comment: @andi So your previous question is already resolved, and this is a completely unrelated issue then?

Comment: I deleted the second one. This case is more intresting for me, and probabbly easier to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason WAS not connected with sending email, but with WRONG using of forms methods by me.

This is the working solution in basic form (without sending email, and without generating new password in some random way) to make it clear for others, who end up here with the same problem of set_password while calling save() of the form in case of AbstractBaseUser

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserChangeForm, self).save(commit=False)
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    old_status = FairsUser.objects.get(email=cleaned_data['email'])
    if (old_status.mail_sent is False or old_status.mail_sent is None) and cleaned_data['mail_sent'] is True:
        new_pass =  "SOME_NEW_VALUE_OF_PASSWORD"
        user.set_password(new_pass)
        # here sending email can be initiated
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```